# Awk command - calculation of columns

Tags: shell, awk, command

I am very new in Awk. 
I want to calculate the difference between first row column2 and second row column2. For instance:

```
Num1 Num2 
23   26
34   39
43   58
63   61
```

So, I want to calculate from Column (Num1) 34-23, 43-34, 63-43. And same for column(Num2). Can you please help me. I can only calculate the value within rows which is `$1 - $2`, but not within column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the old values (from the previous row).

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print $1 - old1, $2 - old2 }
            { old1 = $1; old2 = $2 }' data.file
```

Comment: Hi, one more question:
What if I want to calculate  the difference from row 1 column2 and row 2 colum 1. I mean to say Difference between 34(num1) - 26(num2). Thanks a lot for your help once again!

Comment: You'd print `$1 - old2`, wouldn't you?  You have both old values (previous row values) in `old1` and `old2`; you can combine them with the new values however you like.

Comment: Ahh Ok, now I understand!:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
awk 'NR==1{col1=$1; col2=$2;} { print $1-col1,$2-col2; col1=$1;col2=$2}' yourfile
```